# Can JSF2 use beans as request-based controllers without a framework?

Tags: jsf, controller

I'm working on the development for a web application using Java Server Faces for a group project. The majority of us have experience using request-based frameworks in PHP and we are having problems getting into the event-based (?) mindset of JSF-development.

In PHP you would generally have a front controller (like the Faces Servlet) that dispatches requests to other controllers (unlike the Faces Servlet). The point is that you have full control of the requests from you controllers. This control is something that seems to be lacking in JSF, since the beans are basically just business logic that is not necessarily run when accessing URLs (i.e. by entering the URL for a .xhtml file it will be loaded without the involvement of any beans).

My question is if there is a way to make all requests be handled by managed beans without using a framework such as Spring or Struts (which from I understand are request-based)? This would make the beans more like controllers and, in turn, enable us to manage such things as authentication/authorization, redirects, etc. in a more familiar way.

I hope this makes sense.. Anyhow, me and my group would be very grateful if someone could help us out!

Best regards,
Erik

Comment: JSF can already do it and I fail to understand your misunderstanding, can you please elaborate the functional requirement a bit more? Do you just want to invoke bean actions on GET requests?

Comment: Sure thing! I'd really like it if an URL scheme could be implemented so that the URL was matched to a method in a managed bean, that in turn could select which view to load. This would disallow any direct access to view files, which means you could have authorization logic in the managed bean instead of - as we do now - using a ServletFilter. Does that clear things up? And if that's something JSF does natively, do you know of any resources where one might learn about it?

Comment: Note that what you're describing (mapping URL directly to action method) indicates that you're more in need of a REST webservice than an UI website. JSF is an UI-centric component based MVC framework, not a REST framework. Use the right tools for the job (or the other way round).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) to set request parameters as a managed bean property.

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.foo}")
private Long foo;
```

With http://example.com/page.jsf?foo=123 this will set `123` as `foo`.

You can use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) to indicate a method which has to be executed after the bean is been construct and those managed properties have been set.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    someResult = doSomethingWith(foo);
}
```

---

If you rather want to control this from inside the view side on (the XHTML page), then you can use [`<f:metadata>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html).

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This will basically do `bean.setFoo(request.getParameter("foo"))` during view's construction. In that case, you don't need those annotations, but you won't be able to use the `@PostConstruct` functionality.

#### See also:

- [JSF2 bookmarkability and view parameters](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_bookmarability_view)
- [JSF2 page parameters and page actions](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-page-params-and-page-actions/)
- [What's new in JSF2? - GET support](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#get)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However the question remains how to actually match the URL to a bean, i.e. how to make any request to page.jsf actually construct the PageBean (or whatever it might be called).

Comment: Just bind the bean somewhere in the view the usual way by `#{bean.foo}`. JSF will create and prepare the bean accordingly.

Comment: That will actually be very useful, however this still means that the view decides which bean to be called. The question is rather if one can have the bean be called first and let that in turn decide on the view, instead of the other way around? Though I just saw your comment on the question, and I guess you're correct. The problem is that the group assignment requires us to do it in JSF, so that's why I'm curious if you can somehow modify it's behavior. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Make use of dynamic page includes. E.g. `<ui:include src="#{bean.viewId}.xhtml" />`.